# Get number of a link Shared or Clicked via telegram bot

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

**I'm using [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) module and I want to get number of a link shared by my users to their Friends.**

Users have a `Share Status Button`
Is there a way to display number of a link `Shared` or `Clicked` by User's Friends in `Share Status Button`?

**For example**
1: John's `Share Status Button` : 5 // John Shared to 5 person or 5 person of John's Friends Clicked on that link
2: Maria's `Share Status Button` : 20 // Maria Shared to 20 person or 20 person of Maria's Friends Clicked on that link
.
.
Is it possible?

**Update:**

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `telegram.me/fullmovie_bot?start=${msg.chat.id}`, opts);
  console.log (msg)
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316848/laravel-check-the-user-share-telegram-bot-link-to-other-users/46318044

Comment: Thank you, I'm using java script, how can i get invited From from my msg? ```사이드:
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `telegram.me/fullmovie_bot?start=${msg.chat.id}`, opts);
  console.log (msg)
});```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no directly, but you can get few metrics indirectly.

1. **Number of shares initiated (1)** - use [inline button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) with a callback returning URL. When returning URL update the counter.
2. **Number of shares initiated + sent (2)** - use `switch_inline_query` + [`InlineQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery) + [`answerInlineQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult) + [`chosen_inline_result`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult) to record attemts to share & completed shares. The inline query could be of form `@yourbot invite?id=1234`. This method give you more metrics to your funnel but is less convenient to users
3. **To see ho many times invite was viewed** - Use a private channel and create message here, forward to chat with user and ask to forward as an invite. The message will have counter for views.
4. **To track shares clicked/used** use either callback buttons or URL to server code that tracks clicks or [deeplinks](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) and check `/start` parameters. It can be of form `/start invite?id=123`

Above approaches are successfully used in my bot [@DebtsTrackerBot](https://t.me/DebtsTrackerBot)

Comment: I don't understand number 2 very well, do you have a simple example for number 2?, my bot is sending a link with my bot name + each user id, 
`http://Telegram.me/my_bot?start=76198769`

Comment: Start @DebtsTrackerBot and send /invite command. See how it works.