# how to check url is clicked or not in telegram bot c#

Tags: c#, url, telegram, telegram-bot

I am making telegram bot in c# . I suppose to send link to a user . now How can I check user had clicked on that link .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get number of a link Shared or Clicked via telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428601/get-number-of-a-link-shared-or-clicked-via-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a unique link that opens your bot with a parameter for each user:

```
https://tlgrm.me/harfbemanbot?start=YYYYYYYY
```

or

```
https://tlgrm.me/harfbemanbot?start=XXXXXXX
```

YYYYYYYY and XXXXXXX are Random value.

Then you can get `YYYYYYYY` and `XXXXXXX` value in the backend.

i'm not `c#` developer but i hope [this link](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/162) useful for you .

Answer (score 0):

Telegram will not notify bots when users click links.

You could set up a web-server to work alongside your bot and send the user a custom link that would redirect the user to the correct address while notifying your bot that that link has been used.